# Almost surely time dependent event

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose I know that an event will happen with probability 1 for any fixed time $t\in [a,b]$.

Whether it is possible that by adding extra assumption, I can conclude that the event happens for all $t\in [a,b]$ with probability 1.

If the above question is not possible, whether it is possible to conclude that with a smaller interval e.g the event happens for all $t\in [c,d]$ with probability 1, where $[c,d]\subset [a,b]$?

Comment: In order to get a coherent answer, you'll need to be much more specific; it's impossible to guarantee *anything* at this level of generality. (For instance, what if your event is such that it happens for only one value of $t$?)

Comment: Thanks for you comment. I have a function depends on $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and random variable $\omega$. I know that $f(x,\omega)=x$ almost surely. Now suppose I have a time dependent function $x(t)$ and I fix a $\omega$, I want to know about whether $f(x(t),\omega)=x(t)$

Comment: I'm a bit hesitant here, because I still feel like I don't quite understand what you're trying to do. Your new comment seems like a different question than your original one. That said, regarding your comment, the answer is yes, simply by substitution. Since a random variable is just a function $\Omega \to \mathbb R$, you can regard $f$ as being a function on $\mathbb R \times \Omega$ and the result you want immediately follows. But again, it's not clear to me how you'd interpret that in the way originally posed by your question, which is why I think specificity (or examples?) would help.

Comment: Thanks for your help and patience. One of the example problems in my mind is let $\omega$ be uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$ and  $f(x,\omega)=x$ if $x\neq \omega$, otherwise $f=c$. Therefore if I fix any $x\in [0,1]$ I will have $f(x)=x$ almost surely. Now, I have a time-dependent function $x(t)$ which maps time $t$ to $[0,1]$ and I now fix a $\omega$, what can I say about $f(x(t), \omega)$? I hope the question does make sense.

Comment: My hope is I can say something like $f(x(t),\omega)=x(t)$ "almost every $t$" in finite period of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to extract your comments here somewhat and change your notation just a bit. In the comments, you said this:

> I have a function that depends on $x \in \mathbb R$ and a random variable $Y$. I know that $f(x, Y) = x$ almost surely. Now, suppose I have a time-dependent function $x(t)$ and I fix a value of $Y$. What can I say about $f(x(t), Y)$?

A random variable $Y$ is nothing more than a meausrable function from some (unseen) measure space $\Omega$ to $\mathbb R$. (Also, $\Omega$ should have total measure $1$.) When you say to "fix a $Y$", what you mean -- at least, if I understand what you're going for here -- is to fix a particular $\omega \in \Omega$ and consider $Y(\omega)$. (Intuitively, this is like rolling a die, but exactly specifying the position and eventual motion of your hand, the initial position of the die, the air molecules in the room, etc.)

Your function $f$ is simply a function on $\mathbb R \times \Omega$, where $\mathbb R$ is the time domain and $\Omega$ is the sample space. When you say that $f(x, Y) = x$ almost surely, you mean that for nearly all $\omega \in \Omega$ (i.e. a set of $\omega$ with measure $1$), it holds that $f(x, Y(\omega)) = x$. By a simple substitution, it applies for those same $\omega$ that $f(x(t), Y(\omega)) = x(t)$; hence, this occurs almost surely, like you want. In other words, the desired result trivially applies with no additional restrictions. (Note: this conclusion is predicated on $f(x, Y) = x$ holding for all $x$. Without that, even if excluding just a set of measure $0$, things could get complicated when pulling back to the time domain $\mathbb R$.)

That said, I still have two concerns in giving this answer:

1. It seems to me like this answer I've given, which answers a question laid out in the comments, does not answer your question in your original post. The original question feels unrecognizably different to me than the question that I've answered here.
2. I also confess I don't see the utility of my answer to anything either theoretical or applied, so I'm concerned that there may be a misunderstanding somewhere (very possibly on my part).